# shell command aborts with php exec, but runs perfectly directly in shell (no memory issue)

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

I'm trying to execute a shell script via php exec:

```
gs -sDEVICE=png16m -dNOPAUSE -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4  -dDOINTERPOLATE  -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=%03d.png -r300 ../mydpf.pdf  -dFirstPage=2 -dBATCH -quit;
```

If i run this in the shell it finishes normally, but if I run this using php exec from web it stops after 16 pages are processed and gives no error. here is the output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 2 through 44.
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
Page 5
Page 6
Page 7
Page 8
Page 9
Page 10
Page 11
Page 12
Page 13
Page 14
Page 15
Page 16
Page 17
```

In the PHP file i have:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '18000');
```

So this is not an memory/execution_time issue.
Could You please help me - what could it be, that stops the script?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use shell_exec to be able to see what is being returned.

Comment: yes I'm using it and the return is above (the output)
The shell output is the same, but it runs threw all 44 pages

Comment: It happends also with other scripts - so doesn't depend on gs.
Might it be that the memory or the execution time for shell commands is limited for the web user?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is my workaround, hope it helps:

Create a bash shell script in which you invoke the gs with your parameters, and then run the sh script with PHP exec().